# Adding a table nulls all values in one column

Tags: qgis, table

I've read (and had to deal with) values being changed to "NULL" when joining data from a table to a shapefile. Now I'm having an even more basic problem: for some tables, when I add the table, one of the number/integer columns fills with "Null". Here's what I've done so far:

- My csv file has three columns, one is the County FIPS Code and the other two contain some numeric demographic information (average age and average income).
- I created a .csvt file that states: "String","Integer","Integer"
- Both files are saved in the same directory.
- I've tried adding the table as a vector file (no geometry), as well as a text delimited file. In both cases, the second integer column fills with "Null".
- I've closed an re-opened QGIS several times between each attempt.

Any suggestions for what I can try next?

Image of attribute table here.[image]

Image of original data table in Excel:
[image]

Comment: can you share data to reproduce the issue? or at least screenshots of the attribute tables?

Comment: @underdark I just added an image, not sure if my firewall let it go through though.

Comment: It is not converting all the values to NULL - I see some values in the screen shot. Do those "Null" values actually have data or are they blank? If there is no associated data then the program is doing it's job.

Comment: Please also show the original input layers

Comment: @underdark updated with image of the original Excel table.

Comment: @Stella as all cells within those 3 columns contain data - there are no blank/empty cells, that's why I'm wondering why some numbers are showing but most aren't.

Comment: Remove the commas

Comment: The commas were the problem - thanks, I've been staring at this for so long, I stopped seeing them. When joined with a shapefile layer, some are still showing as Null. I realise this is a join issue - should I start a new question?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not start a new question, but please do accept this official answer:

The numbers in your original document are formatted with commas. Remove the commas since they are causing the Null values. This is a common issue when transferring table data into GIS. It has happened to me before... on multiple occasions.

As for the erroneous NULLs that remain, be sure to double check that they are formatted correctly - no spaces! Can you share your table?

Comment: pointing out the formatting issue was very helpful.  I then went back into the .csv file, removed all commas and checked for extra punctuation. I was still seeing some Nulls which I guessed was due to the FIPS codes being converted to "Number" in Excel whenever I opened the table in Excel. So in Excel, I set all the FIPS cells as "Text" and then in the csvt, I replaced the very last "Integer" with "Real" so when the table was imported into QGIS, it would recognize the decimals.   So in the end, my csvt line was: "String"(3),"String"(15),"Integer","Real"

Comment: Glad you were able o resolve this @N.Doole